# Tomcat 7 is not running on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7

I installed tomcat7, but once I try to log on `(http://localhost:8080)` using my default browser (firefox) it won't work.

```
Unable to connect
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at `(http://localhost:8080)`.
```

Although when I started it from the terminal # sh startup.sh I get the right messages :

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_23/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Tomcat started.
```

Comment: did you check which ports/ips that tomcat is listening to? `netstat -tan`-type thing? It might be running on :8080, but not listening to localhost.

Comment: Here the output I get when `netstat -tan |grep 127.0.0.1`

`tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN     
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:631 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN     
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:9000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN     
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:3306 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN     
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:35019 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN     
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:51340 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN     
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:38822 127.0.0.1:4369 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:35019 127.0.0.1:56076 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:56076 127.0.0.1:35019 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:4369 127.0.0.1:38822 ESTABLISHED
`
I guess it's not listening so? and how could I correct it? Thx